# How to list root classes of an ontology in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

I am trying to list root classes of the [NIF ontology](https://github.com/SciCrunch/NIF-Ontology/tree/master/ttl) which is an ontology created of several other ontologies as its modules.
I use this code from an [online resource](https://codyburleson.com/sparql-examples-list-classes/):

```
SELECT ?directSub ?super
 WHERE { ?directSub rdfs:subClassOf ?super .
         FILTER NOT EXISTS {
            ?directSub rdfs:subClassOf ?otherSub .
            FILTER (?otherSub != ?directSub)
         }
}
```

The logic of the code seems fine but it does not return any answers (even when I test it on other ontologies)! Why is that?

Comment: from where do you have this query? It doesn't make any sense

Comment: and regarding why, just read the query one more time, it's so obvious that it doesn't work, the `FILTER NOT EXISTS` is the opposite of the outer triple pattern, so it's always empty. Next, think about the definition of *"root class"*, what does that mean? The absence of being the subclass of some other class, right? How do you express this via a triple pattern? Try it yourself first please, if that doesn't work, tell me

Comment: @AKSW I have updated the question with the link to the resource. You can find it [here](https://codyburleson.com/sparql-examples-list-classes/) too. Previously, I've used `?c1 rdfs:subClassOf ?c2. ?c2 rdfs:subClassOf ?c3` and so on, to get to the root. But that one needed the depth of the branch. However, maybe I could have used the `optional` keyword to avoid potential issues.

Comment: After your comment, I tried this: `select distinct ?c1
{ 
    ?c1 a owl:Class.
    ?c2 a owl:Class.

 

    filter not exists{?c1 rdfs:subClassOf ?c2}
  }
` It seems it's doing the job. But I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Ok, I see - as said before, the query from the link is just wrong. Regarding your solution, yes - that's a way. But it will only work if you have OWL ontologies and the triple `:c rdf:type owl:Class` explicitly exists in the RDF serialization. The other way could be `select distinct ?root {
?sub rdfs:subClassOf ?root 
filter not exists {?root rdfs:subClassOf ?otherSup filter(?otherSup != owl:Thing)}
}`

Comment: The query you mentioned is very good. Because I was looking for a way to avoid the 'Thing' node.

Answer (score 0):

The @UninformedUser's answer works fine. However, there is an exception that does not work with that solution, which is a root class without any child. The solution assumes that all roots have subclasses, which is not always true.

The following piece of code can find these classes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?exClass  
WHERE {  
    ?exClass rdf:type owl:Class  
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?subClass rdfs:subClassOf ?exClass }  
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?exClass rdfs:subClassOf ?supClass }}
```

Hence, the full SPARQL query for finding all root nodes is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?rootClass 
WHERE {{  
    ?rootClass rdf:type owl:Class . 
    ?subClass rdf:type owl:Class . 
    ?subClass rdfs:subClassOf ?rootClass 
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
        ?rootClass rdfs:subClassOf ?otherSup 
        FILTER (?otherSup != owl:Thing)} 
    } UNION { 
        ?rootClass rdf:type owl:Class 
        FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?subClass rdfs:subClassOf ?rootClass } 
        FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?rootClass rdfs:subClassOf ?supClass }}}
```

I am sure that the above pieces of code can be improved, however, I am just a beginner. I really would appreciate it if someone can provide tips on how to improve it.